# Test getter in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-material, jasmine

In my project I am using mat-menu:

```
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
     [matMenuTriggerData]="menuTriggerData"
     (menuOpened)="isMenuOpen()"
     (menuClosed)="isMenuClose()">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-menuListWidth='menuListWidth'>
        <div [style.width.px]="menuListWidth">
            <button *ngFor="let item of menuItems"
                (click)="onClick(item.value)">
                {{ item.name }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

To calculate the width of the overlay, I use the getter function:

```
export class MenuComponent {
    @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, { static: true, read: ElementRef })
    menuElementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

    get menuTriggerData() {
        return {
            menuListWidth: this.menuElementRef.nativeElement.clientWidth
        };
    }
}
```

In the .spec file, I am doing the test:

```
it('getter should be defined', function () {
    spyOnProperty(component, 'menuTriggerData', 'get').and.returnValue({menuListWidth: 150});
    expect(component.menuTriggerData).toEqual({menuListWidth: 150});
}
```

The test succeeds, but there is no getter coverage.
What needs to be added to the test to cover the getter in the component?

Answer (score 1):

There's no test coverage because you overwrite the getter with `spyOnProperty` that returns a value. Therefore, the actual getter won't be invoked.

You can however use `spyOnProperty` to mock the readonly [`Element.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) property returned by the method `menuTriggerData`. This could look as follows:

```
it('getter should be defined', function () { 
  spyOnProperty(component.menuElementRef.nativeElement, 'clientWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(150);
  expect(component.menuTriggerData).toEqual({ menuListWidth: 150});
}
```

Comment: But webstorm lights up the error:
Cannot assign to 'clientWidth' because it is a read-only property.

Comment: @Alex: I updated my answer accordingly. I hope this solution works now.

Comment: With the latest changes, I am getting the error: 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'.
But I wrote it like this and the cover worked:
component.menuElementRef = {nativeElement: {clientWidth: 150}} as ElementRef<HTMLElement>
I'm not sure if this is correct.